# Exchange powershell, filtering part string for SamAccountname export

Tags: powershell, pipe, exchange-server

I am using Exchange 2010 and trying to run a PowerShell to export all users that have a User mailbox, I am using the PowerShell below

```
Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited -recipienttypedetails UserMailbox | Get-MailboxPermission | export-csv c:\User_mailbox.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

However our environment hasn't been consistent when creating User Mailboxes, there are some Shared Mailboxes that appear as User Mailboxes when I look through the above-exported file.

Is there a way I can add a filter, attribute or pipe in the PowerShell command so only the 'User' field pulls data that are numeric values and not alpha values?

This is because I know a User Mailbox will only have numbers as their SamAccountname example `11368` and won't be `joe.bloggs`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to explicitly filter the Shared Mailboxes out:

```
Get-Mailbox -resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | 
    Where-Object { @($_.RecipientTypeDetails) -notcontains 'SharedMailbox' } | 
    Get-MailboxPermission | 
    Export-Csv c:\User_mailbox.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Perhaps also the `-Filter` works more precise in your case:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter "RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox'"
```

**Edit**

To also filter for the SamAccountName to be numeric, you can do something like this (*untested*):

```
Get-Mailbox -resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | 
    Where-Object { @($_.RecipientTypeDetails) -notcontains 'SharedMailbox' -and $_.SamAccountName -match '^\d+$'} | 
    Get-MailboxPermission | 
    Export-Csv c:\User_mailbox.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

or by using `-Filter`

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {(RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (SamAccountName -match '^\d+$')}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Theo.  This does work better for me.  Is there any chance I can add another filter for the SamAccountName so that it only returns Numeric Values?

Comment: I have edited my answer with code for that. However I cannot test this out myself at the moment.. Let me know.

Comment: Hi Theo, the first powershell command does not export the SamAccount Field, it exports a User field.  I changed and $_.SamAccountName to say User, but that does not export anything, file size is 0kb.  the second powershell which has the -Filter comes back with an error to say

Comment: this is the error when running the -filter Invoke-Command : Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter": ""-match" is not a valid operator. For a list of supported operators see the command help.
"(RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (SamAccountName -match '^\d+$')" at position 63."